# Python in-place unpacking doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've seen a lot of questions on here about using `*` before a tuple to expand it into something else, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
>>> l1 = (1, 2, 3)
>>> l2 = (0, l1, 4)
>>> l2   (0, (1, 2, 3), 4)
>>> l2 = (0, *l1, 4)
File "<stdin>", line 1  
    l2 = (0, *l1, 4)  
             ^   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As you can see. I can't get l1 to expand into l2 with the `*` operator...

Note: This is python2.7

Comment: It's just not possible. Just do `l2 = (0,)+l1+(4,)`

Comment: This only works on relatively recent versions of Python 3.

Comment: What version are you using? That extended tuple unpacking is a relatively late addition to Python 3

Comment: "I've seen a lot of questions on here about using * before a tuple to expand it into something else" - those questions were about function calls. The syntax wasn't expanded to tuple construction until fairly recently.

Comment: Also, you never once use a list here, so be careful with terminology. You are using tuples.

Comment: And this is why it is very important to specify your version of Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpack list into middle of a tuple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738275/unpack-list-into-middle-of-a-tuple)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In-place unpacking has been introduced in python 3.5 and it works in later versions not older ones.

```
# Python 3.5
In [39]: (3, *l1, 4)
Out[39]: (3, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

In older versions you can use `+` operator or `itertools.chain` function for longer iterables:

```
In [40]: (3,) + l1 + (4,)
Out[40]: (3, 1, 2, 3, 4)

In [41]: from itertools import chain

In [45]: tuple(chain((3,), l1, (4,)))
Out[45]: (3, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Put commas in the arguments to `chain`.

Comment: It's either chain or +, not both

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, fixed!

Comment: You probably just want `chain.((3,), l1, (4,))`

Comment: @Kasramvd. I went ahead and truncated further. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks that even better ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, those aren't `lists`, they're `tuples`.  They are similar but not the same thing.

Second, the `*arg` syntax is called *argument expansion*, and it only works for *function arguments*

```
def func(a, b):
    return a + b

my_list = [1, 2]
func(*my_list)
```

EDIT:

Apparently, in-place unpacking was added in python 3.5, but for the overwhelming majority of python installations you encounter, my answer still holds true.  Perhaps in 2020 when Python 2 stops being supported this will change, but for now and the immediate future, expect the above to be true.

Comment: And this is why it is important to specify your version of Python.

Comment: Thanks, though, the user is clearly using python 2.  Python 3 is still in relatively little use, let alone 3.5.

Comment: While it is true that OP is clearly using something prior to version 3.5 (maybe 2, but maybe an earlier 3) and for those versions your answer is adequate, your answer is nevertheless misleading for readers of later versions of Python. At the very least, you should mention this.

Comment: You are needlessly snarky about Python 2 vs Python 3 (in data science , for instance, Python 3 is making rapid gains: http://ianozsvald.com/2016/06/20/results-for-which-version-of-python-2vs3-do-london-data-scientists-use/ ) but you answer is otherwise fine now, so +1.